# How to get specific date format

Tags: c#

How to get the date in the format "2020-11-02T13:20:00Z"?

```
string datestring = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

This gives me a result in the required format. The problem here is it is converted to string. How can I get this in DateTime datatype. I tried with `ParseExact` but didn't get this format.

Comment: Isn't `DateTime.Now` already in "DateTime format"?

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format.  Formats are for the string representations and are used to parse from or format to string.

Comment: can i get a datetime variable this way 2020-11-02T13:20:00Z

Comment: What are you using to display the date?

Comment: I dont display it, i pass as a request parameter to a client application, and there the service is considering it as a filter to retrieve data

Comment: Note that `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")` is wrong. It should be `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")`, since the "Z" means UTC+0. The "Z", pronounced "zulu", represents a Zero offset from UTC.

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime` does not *have* a format. You decide the format (or the system decides it for you) when the data is displayed or serialized. So whatever is displaying or serializing your date (app, form, report, API, whatever) needs to specify the format.

Comment: DateTime x=  2020-11-02T13:20:00Z . My client application expecting date field this way

Comment: But in this case, you need serialize the date to string for sending to your client. So you Can send the string representation you need and let the Client deceide how to handle dates.

Comment: @User1Bas You don't give any details on how you are interacting with the "client application". Does it use a JSON or other API? That layer is where you specify the format, and you don;t give any detail on what that layer is.

Comment: [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://V2/B/CRM/I7754/MyService")]
    public partial class getMyData
    {

        private string myGuidField;

        private System.DateTime tripDateFromField;

     

        private System.DateTime tripDateToField;
}

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime object is an abstract representation of a date and time.

`2020-11-02T13:20:00Z` is a string.

`DateTime(2020, 11, 2, 13, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` and `"2020-11-02T13:20:00Z"` both represent the same date-time, but they are different values with different types. A value can be one or the other, but not both.

---

To convert a DateTime into a string of the specified format, you can use

```cs
dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    Console.WriteLine(dateString);
    
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    dateString = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    Console.WriteLine(dateString);
```

output

```
2021-11-30T12:45:53Z

2021-11-30T12:45:53Z
```